# Very slow conversion from dataframe to dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have this snippet of code that converts a dataframe to a dictionary of dictionaries using the first column as the reference index. However, its execution is very slow as that daraframe has a total of 250,000 rows. Additionally, I have good hardware (32GB RAM and an i7) which is not the bottleneck in this case.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to transform the dataframe into a dictionary-of-dictionaries.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, nrows=nrows)
colname_asindex = df.columns[0]

df.set_index(colname_asindex, inplace=True)
dd1 = df.to_dict('dict')
```

The goal to use the resulting dictionary of dictionaries for an apply:

```
df['col5'].apply(mapdict['mycol_mapping'])
```

Comment: what are you really trying to achieve here? also you've set the index twice in your code when you could've just done this in `read_csv`: `df= pd.read_csv(csvfile,  nrows=nrows, index_col=[0])`, also note that if your `colname` values are not unique then you're going to just produce the last row of values for that key

Comment: I want to use the dict as mapping for df['col5'].apply(mapdict['mycol_mapping'])

Comment: `apply` receives a function as input. Is `mapdict['mycol_mapping']` a function? It is really not clear what you're trying to do.
If you need it for a lookup in a different `DataFrame`, you might want to consider [`merge` or `join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-join).

Comment: lambda x: mapping["col"][x]

Comment: Potentially changing the dtypes of things in your dataframe to lower precision will lower the memory footprint and speed things up.

Comment: `dict.__getitem__` is the method associated with looking up a dict. But you don't need to use an apply, in pandas you can directly do `df['col5'].map(...)` e.g. `df['col5'].map(mapdict['mycol_mapping'].__getitem__)`, this could be faster. Please post us a snippet of your data, random-seeded data is fine.